# determine returned code format

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to find out what this format is:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:2:"29";i:1;s:2:"30";}
```

It kind of looks like json. To give background information I am using php/drupal with the webform module and submitting a form returns one of the input fields as this value for a fileupload box.

I am trying to get the 29 and 30. Hopefully there is an easy way to grab those two numbers without having to parse the string using regular expressions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a serialized array.

You can get the value with PHP by:

`$value = unserialize('a:2:{i:0;s:2:"29";i:1;s:2:"30";}');`

You can read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php